# Unity, JSON file - Android problem, can't find my JSON file

Tags: android, json, unity-game-engine

I wrote a script that allows you to read and write to a json file. As long as I tried the script in unity editor, I didn't have any problems. But when I switched to installing the application on an Android device, I can't find my json file.

The json file is called "playerData.json" and has been placed in a folder called "playerData.json".

This is the code for the path of the json file (working on unity but not working on android)

```
path = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/playerData.json";
```

I tried using this string of code to get the code to work on android as well, but there is no way to get it to work.

```
path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "/playerData.json");
```

I only wrote the line concerning the path as my android device cannot find the JSON file. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Application.streamingAssetsPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html) does not work on Android and WebGL

> It is not possible to access the StreamingAssets folder on WebGL and Android platforms. No file access is available on WebGL. Android uses a compressed .apk file. These platforms return a URL. Use the UnityWebRequest class to access the Assets.

There is a workaround though as mentioned using UnityWebRequest, can find an example in this [Unity Answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1696349/view.html)